# Incorrect output when smoothing line that intersects multiline with PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, line, intersection, multipart, smoothing

I wrote a such script to smooth my line. It checks whether a line of two points intersects the border of a polygon and, if not, then draws a line.

This script works well for a simple example, but bad for this example. For some reason it always reduces the line to two points (start and end) and the intersection condition is not met. The boundary line is a Multiline in both cases.

Can anyone help me fix the condition so that the script runs correctly?

```py
point_layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("888 Vertices")[0]
path=[]
for feature in point_layer.getFeatures():
    geom = feature.geometry()
    point = geom.asPoint()
    path.append((point.x(), point.y()))
    print(point)
print(len(path))


bound_layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("9 boundary 3 collected")[0]
feature = bound_layer.getFeature(1)

if len(path) > 2:
    k=0
    t=[]
    t.append(path[0])
    for i in range(1, len(path)-1):   
        if QgsGeometry.fromPolylineXY([QgsPointXY(t[k][0], t[k][1]),QgsPointXY(path[i+1][0], path[i+1][1])]).intersects(feature.geometry()):
            k+=1
            t.append(path[i])
    k+=1
    t.append(path[-1])
    
print(len(t))    
print(t)


vl = QgsVectorLayer(f"LineString?crs={point_layer.crs().authid()}", "smoothed_path", "memory")

pr = vl.dataProvider()

# Create a new feature
seg = QgsFeature()

# Add the shortest path to the feature as a polyline
seg.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPolyline([QgsPoint(pt[0], pt[1]) for pt in t]))

# Add the feature to the layer
pr.addFeatures([seg])

# Update extent of the layer
vl.updateExtents()
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(vl)
```

For this example it works good and really reduces the source line:

[image]

But it doesn't work for this example at all (orange = boundary line, yellow = source line and blue = smoothed line, it's incorrect). Blue line should be at least the same as yellow line but a little but smoothed, without unnecessary vertices.

[image]

I have loaded my data in here: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1NH4wE1u8wii5c1MK-s17deC-QLDj1Ox9?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several suggestions regarding your code:

- Break your *'9 boundary 3 collected'* lines with the ["Multipart to singleparts"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#qgismultiparttosingleparts):

  ```py
  bound_layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("9 boundary 3 collected")[0]
  params = {
     'INPUT': bound_layer,
     'OUTPUT': 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'
     }
  bound_layer_single = processing.run("native:multiparttosingleparts", params)['OUTPUT']
  bound_features = [feature.geometry() for feature in bound_layer_single.getFeatures()]
  ```
- check each feature for intersection separately by means of the Python's built-in function [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any)

  ```py
  if any(line.intersects(bound_feature) for bound_feature in bound_features):
  ```
- append values to the `path = []` directly as a [`QgsPointXY`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsPointXY.html)-object, no need to create a tuple with coordinates i.e. `(point.x(), point.y())` and after reconstructing them back. Then your code will be also simplified in this line:

  ```py
  if QgsGeometry.fromPolylineXY([QgsPointXY(t[k][0], t[k][1]), path[i+1]]).intersects(feature.geometry())
  ```
- [Python - List Comprehension](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp) is a great asset to create the `path`-object:

  ```py
  path = [QgsPointXY(feature.geometry().asPoint()) for feature in point_layer.getFeatures()]
  print(len(path)) #58
  ```
- The `t`-list with its `QgsPoint`-objects can be adjusted via the [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) function combined with the [`lambda`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#lambda):

  ```py
  points = list(map(lambda point: QgsPoint(point), t))
  # Add the shortest path to the feature as a polyline
  seg.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPolyline(points))
  ```
- Sometimes the order of coordinates of a point can swap, therefore use the corresponding methods e.g. [`x()`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsPointXY.html#a031c77e7533369f55cbd85b52cd4ed1f) and [`y()`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsPointXY.html#ab6d04669c5b31a8ad56bef4385e8f359) of the `QgsPointXY` class:

  ```py
  if QgsGeometry.fromPolylineXY([QgsPointXY(t[k].x(), t[k].y()), path[i+1]]).intersects(feature.geometry()):
  ```

  But the `QgsGeometry`-object you intended to achieve can be initiated even easier:

  ```py
  if QgsGeometry.fromPolylineXY([t[k], path[i+1]]).intersects(feature.geometry()):
  ```

  See, that the `t[k]`-variable is of the `QgsPointXY`-class type. The [`QgsGeometry::fromPolylineXY`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsGeometry.html#a4bec85aab9d4adc70c37164cb9efc526) creates a new `LineString` geometry from a list of `QgsPointXY` points.
- Imports can be useful to make your code reusable in the future in standalone applications:

  ```py
  # imports
  import processing
  from qgis.core import (QgsProject, QgsVectorLayer, QgsPointXY, QgsPoint, QgsFeature, QgsGeometry)
  ```
- leave comments in your code

So, in the end, your code may look like this:

```py
# imports
import processing
from qgis.core import (QgsProject, QgsVectorLayer, QgsPointXY, QgsPoint, QgsFeature, QgsGeometry)

point_layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("888 Vertices")[0]

path = [QgsPointXY(feature.geometry().asPoint()) for feature in point_layer.getFeatures()]

bound_layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("9 boundary 3 collected")[0]
params = {
    'INPUT': bound_layer,
    'OUTPUT': 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'
    }
bound_layer_single = processing.run("native:multiparttosingleparts", params)['OUTPUT']
bound_features = [feature.geometry() for feature in bound_layer_single.getFeatures()]

if len(path) > 2:
    k, t = 0, []
    t.append(path[0])
    for i in range(1, len(path) - 1):
        line = QgsGeometry.fromPolylineXY([t[k], path[i + 1]])
        if any(line.intersects(bound_feature) for bound_feature in bound_features):
            k += 1
            t.append(path[i])
    k += 1
    t.append(path[-1])

vl = QgsVectorLayer(f"LineString?crs={point_layer.crs().authid()}", "smoothed_path", "memory")

pr = vl.dataProvider()

# Create a new feature
seg = QgsFeature()

points = list(map(lambda point: QgsPoint(point), t))
# Add the shortest path to the feature as a polyline
seg.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPolyline(points))

# Add the feature to the layer
pr.addFeatures([seg])

# Update extent of the layer
vl.updateExtents()
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(vl)
```

And then it should work as supposed.

[image: result]